# How to use postgres `array_agg` with typeorm?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

In NestJS I am trying to get a list of categories as an array using TypeORM.

In PostgreSQL I can just do:

```
'SELECT array_agg(name) AS categories FROM categories;';
```

Is there a way to do this with TypeORM using `createQueryBuilder` ?

Comment: [`.select(['array_agg(name) as categories'])`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/7215)